# JavaScript runtime error: Object expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I m trying to reproduce HighChart graph .it is working fine on JsFiddle ..but on My local web app it is throwing Error :

> JavaScript runtime error: Object expected

Error comes on this code segment in file highcharts.src.js

```
/ Set up auto resize
        if (optionsChart.reflow !== false) {
            addEvent(chart, 'load', function () {
                chart.initReflow();
            });
        }
```

this I my JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/u9xES/550/

this is my WebPage

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(function () {
                var highOptions = {

                    chart: {
                        type: 'line',
                        renderTo: 'container2',
                        zoomType: 'x',
                        marginTop: 100

                    },

                    title: {
                        text: 'Score'
                    },

                    subtitle: {
                        text: '  '
                    },

                    xAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'XXX'
                        },
                        categories: [],
                        labels: {
                            rotation: 45,
                            step: 1,
                            y: 30
                        }
                    },

                    yAxis: [{ // left y axis
                        title: {
                            text: 'XXX'
                        },
                        min: 0,
                        max: 9,
                        plotLines: [{
                            value: 7.5,
                            color: '#ff0000',
                            width: 2,
                            zIndex: 4,
                            label: {
                                text: 'XXX'
                            }
                        }]
                    }],

                    plotOptions: {
                        column: {
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true,
                                formatter: function () {
                                    return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 1);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        align: 'left',
                        verticalAlign: 'top',
                        y: 20,
                        floating: true,
                        borderWidth: 0
                    },

                    tooltip: {
                        shared: true,
                        crosshairs: true
                    },
                    series: []
                };

                highOptions.xAxis.categories = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8];

                highOptions.subtitle.text = "XXX:";
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(highOptions);
                var aName = "Fin";

                newLP = [0.1, 5.52, 0.2, 6.16, 0.3, 6.34, 0.4, 6.69, 0.5, 6.36, 0.6, 7.44, 0.7,  
                7.44, 0.8, 7.44];

                    chart.addSeries({
                        name: aName,
                        data: newLP
                    }, false);

                chart.redraw();
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="container2">
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not getting any idea ..why it is running fine on JSFiddle .But not on my Web App ..there is no other plugin install ..please suggest

Comment: It's next to impossible to fix a bug without seeing it recreated. Logic would dictate that the object expected error is not caused by the code you have here. If you check the error in the console it should tell you the line of JS code which caused it. This should help you debug the problem

Comment: I have mentioned the segment where I am finding error on Runtime ..Hope this might be Helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence of the scripts are important in this case, the correct sequence **FOR CHROME** should be:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

Other browsers may have different methods in determining which js file to load first. So you have to test with other browsers if they all work fine.

Answer (score -1):

Just googling around a bit for that error, and it seems that it always has to deal with how

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

is defined.

Have you tried changing it to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
```